# Array Bounds cannot appear in type specifier

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I keep having this error within a line of my code and I can't seem to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
con.Open()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim ds As DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select From * product info", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    With newRow
        .Item("Product Name:") = txtItemName.Text
        .Item("Description") = txtDescription.Text
        .Item("Quantity:") = txtItemCount.Text
        .Item("Type:") = cmbItemType.Text
        .Item("Date Received:") = txtDate.Text
        .Item("Barcode:") = txtBarcode.Text
        .Item("Price:") = txtPrice.Text
    End With

    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Update(dt)
    con.Close()
```

In the `Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder(da)` line I get the error on the `da`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed the initialization and declaration of the variable **cb**.
The correct syntax to use is

```
Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
```

or

```
Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder      'declaration
cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da)   'initialization
```

or (as explained by Konrad below)

```
Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
```

Comment: While both work, neither way is recommended in VB! The “correct” way is to contract declaration and initialisation: `Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)`. The first method you’ve shown is simply unnecessarily verbose. The second has the added disadvantage that it needlessly separates declaration and initialisation. This is something that shouldn’t ever be done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Steve. I fixed that error but i continously get more errors. Can you suggest a code or a page that shows a code on how to insert datas into ms access database?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, It was only for clarity. A downvote seems a bit exagerate. However, I will add your way to the answer

Comment: … and the downvote magically transformed ;) (I do *really* feel strong about teaching best practice)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, tried your suggestion with LinqPad and looking to the IL code there are no difference between the 3 methods. Could you explain why your proposed approach is better? (I'm not actively using vb,net now so I am a bit rusty)

Comment: @Steve the first two, because it applies the DRY principle. The repetition of the type name is gratuitous. As for tearing apart declaration and initialisation, there’s similarly simply no reason to ever do that: It’s twice as long. Worse, it opens the door to other un-initialised variables. While VB *does* default initialise all values for you, I consider every uninitialised variable a bug waiting to happen. You simply do *not* want variables whose state is uncertain in your code. Reasoning about code correctness is hard enough with explicit state. Don’t introduce implicit state as well.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks, it is a very enlightening comment. I'll keep this for the future.

Comment: @RaraArar, please post a new question explaining the problems you are getting.

Comment: How about i just post it here? Im getting a new error when i hit the save button in my program. 

In this line: ds.Tables.Add(dt)
I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.